# Android | Different raw resource folder for different product flavour

Tags: android, android-productflavors

I am using product flavors and able to create different strings.xml for different flavors but when I try to create raw folder under res for different flavors, I am unable to access files under raw folder for that flavor, instead it is referring to main's raw folder file for every flavor.

Use case - I need json files (files saved with same name under different flavor folders) with different content for different flavors.
I want to access these files using `R.raw.xyz`

project structure:-

```
  app
    --src
        --dev
           --res
              --values/strings.xml
              --raw/xyz.json

        --production
           --res
              --values/strings.xml
              --raw/xyz.json

        --main
           --res
              --values/strings.xml
              --raw/xyz.json
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should configure [sourceSets](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#sourcesets) (here you have the full manual).

> By default, Android Studio creates the main/ source set and directories for everything you want to share between all your build variants. However, you can create new source sets to control exactly what files Gradle compiles and packages for specific build types, product flavors (and combinations of product flavors when using flavor dimensions), and build variants.

This is your case, and finally in the project structure it `somehow` should look like below:

```
android {
  ...
  sourceSets {
    main {
      java.srcDirs = ['other/java']
      res.srcDirs = ['src/all/res']
      manifest.srcFile 'other/AndroidManifest.xml'
      ...
    }
    production {
      res.srcDirs = ['src/production/res']
      ...
    }
    dev {
      res.srcDirs = ['src/dev/res']
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: res4 & res3 are folders or files? since in my case "raw" is sub folder of" res" and from your answer it seems reverse. and for strings.xml,  I am getting different files for different flavors.

Comment: As you can see, `srcDirs` indicates that you point to folders. `raw` is subfolder of `res`, so it should be visible for the IDE. Also, when you set up proper source sets, plat with BuildVariants (left side of Android Studio) and check whether you applied your config correctly.